# Python: remove duplicate items in a list

Tags: python

Assume a list:

```
A = ['a','a','a','b','b','c','c','c']
```

I want to convert A to B:

```
B = ['a','b','c']
```

Is there an efficient way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

I got it by using set function:

```
B = list(set(A))
```

But this function may change the order in which the unique items are arranged in the sequence.